# How Make AJAX REQUEST with clicking in the link not submit button

Tags: jquery

How could I make an AJAX REQUEST by clicking on a link instead of a submit button?
I want once the link is clicked to POST data from input fields

Comment: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials , scroll down to the heading AJAX. Additional tip: you should read up on JavaScript events, especially "onclick"

Answer (score 12):

```
$('selector').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
       url: "<where to post>",
       type: "POST",//type of posting the data
       data: <what to post>,
       success: function (data) {
         //what to do in success
       },
       error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
          //what to do in error
       },
       timeout : 15000//timeout of the ajax call
  });

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can user JQuery and the Form serialize functionality

```
$('#A-id-selector').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST', 
        url: 'target.url', 
        data:$('#Form-id-selector').serialize(), 
        success: function(response) {
          // Any code to execute on a successful return
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's how AJAX works:

```
$('#link_id').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault(); // prevent default behavior of link click
   // now make an AJAX request to server_side_file.php by passing some data
   $.post('server_side_file.php', {parameter : some_value}, function(response){
      //now you've got `response` from server, play with it like
      alert(response);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery

```
$('#link-selector').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post('url', {$('form selector').serialize()}, function(json) {
        // proccess results
    }, 'json');
});
```

Comment: url as in link. Selector is form/link id or class, just like in css