# How to get jQuery Ui Tabs to "read" children

Tags: jquery, user-interface, tabs

im having trouble getting jQuery Ui Tabs to work with my setup.
Basically it works fine on Ul li's, but wont read ul li ul li's (links in submenu's of my navigation. Here is my setup simplified:

```
<div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">ONE</a></li>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="ajax/test.php">TWO</a>
                    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="ajax/testA.php">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/testB.php">B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/testC.php">C</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ajax/test2.php">THREE</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
<div id="tabs-1">
<p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
</div>
```

One, Two and Three work perfectly fine, but A B C will send me to the link instead of pulling it with ajax.
I think im missing something in my script wich is just:

```
     <script>
          $(function() {
        $( ".navigation" ).tabs();
      });
     </script>
```

But im quite unsure on how to act.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine for me, if I follow the format as in jquery ui's [tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/),

You need to give id to your ul as this,

```
<div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">ONE</a></li>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="#tabs-2">TWO</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">THREE</a></li>
            </ul>
            <ul id="tabs-2" class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="ajax/testA.php">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/testB.php">B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/testC.php">C</a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
```

Check the [tabs documentation](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/).

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO 1](http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/28/)**

If you are looking for second id to be tabs too,

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2rfm5/30/)**

And after you I saw the link you gave me, the child ul too needs to be tabbed so that you can get contents using ajax, just by providing a href attribute.

**EDIT,**

I made two files,

```
maindir
 - index.html
 - ajax (directory)
      -- testB.php
```

**index.html,**

```
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="description" edit="mootools shell, easy test you snippets before implementing"/>
  <meta name="keywords" edit="mootools,javascript,javascript framework,shell,test"/>
  <meta name="robots" edit="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jqueryui.com/tabs/resources/demos/style.css" />

</head>

<body>
<div class="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1">ONE</a></li>
                <li class="sub">
                    <a href="#tabs-2">TWO</a>

                </li>
                <li><a href="#tabs-3">THREE</a></li>
            </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.</p>
    </div>
    <div  id="tabs-2">
    <ul class="submenu">
                        <li><a href="ajax/testA.php">A</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/testB.php">B</a></li>
                        <li><a href="ajax/testC.php">C</a></li>
        </ul></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $( ".navigation" ).tabs();
       $("#tabs-2").tabs();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

**testB.php,**

```
<?php

echo "content of B";

?>
```

And it shows me this,

[image]

From comments,

> In jquery-ui, you can directly give link to get content via ajax. Well
>   then the problem is, the children ul li ul li, are not tabbed. I guess
>   if that was tabbed too, then only you can use it to get content via
>   ajax. As in my first fiddle example, you click on an href, it
>   redirects you to show 404. But in second fiddle, it has a link but is
>   tabbed, it does not redirect but gets contents via ajax. So basically
>   you just need to do it like the second example. Just do
>   $("#tab-2").tabs(), this should solve your problem.

Comment: Ah i see what you mean, but is there no way to work around it and let it dig into children? I tried moving stuff around in my structure, but it all breaks up because a lot of stuff is relying on that gerarchy (sliders, css, icons) and i have no idea how to go and fix it :(

For example if i structure it exactly like you did, the submenu comes out under the nav instead of under the clicked li, and with the style of the menu not the submenu.

Comment: I could but i see now my mistake in explaining myself, i had been awake 24 straight hours. I did not mean children inside the tabs, but children of the menu itself. So my geriarchy is exactly like in my question, i had only omitted the "<ul id="tabs-2"> because it was irrelevant.
I do not have need for tabs inside my tabs, but the script does not read the children of my ul li's (ul li ul li's).
Basically for example if i had:

`HOME
CARS
-ALFA ROMEO
-BMW
-DACIA
EMAIL`

Home, Cars and Email will work fine for tabs, but Alfa Romeo, Bmw and Dacia will not.

Comment: I rectified my question to include the tabs-2 ul.

Comment: Ok, this is much simpler if i show the actual problem :) Go to http://77.235.53.36/garage.php , you will see that the defaul phrase is loaded. If you click on Management, it will load with ajax another file. But if you click on an element of Management's submenu (staff) you will see it sends you to the page but it wont load it dynamically.

Comment: But the management tab is also linking to a php file, and it works. Everything i am using is in my question, aside from including jquery and jquery ui. As in my question "TWO" will work, but "A" wont, both with a php link but A is in the submenu of TWO.

Comment: You may see this link, I guess there is something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734749/how-make-ajax-request-with-clicking-in-the-link-not-submit-button

Comment: The example in my question is exactly how it is in my code, i think (i know very little about all this) that the piece of ajax in the second code of my question tells it to treat all li's hrefs as ajax calls to substitute their href's php file to tab-1, by using the jquery ui library. Problem is that it wont look in ul li ul li's.

Comment: I tried, and nothing. I also tried `$( ".submenu" ).tabs();` since thats where the actual li's are contained by nothing as well. As you can see the function tells it to look inside the navigation div, so im starting to think this is simply a jQuery ui limitation and there is nothing i can do about it. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: It does work for the children too, if they are tabbed. When I removed `$("#tabs-2").tabs()`, it redirected me to the php page, just sayinh "contents of B";

Comment: I see, but you created a second set of tabs inside another tab. What i need is all the tabs to be part of the same "array", links in the navi and the subnavi are all supposed to load .php pages in the same space, and considered equal.

Comment: Then just don't put A, B, C in a different ul. If you have to change styles, just add some other class to A, B, C li's.

Comment: Its not about style but function, as you see http://77.235.53.36/garage.php the child ul's only display when a parent li is clicked, the javascript responsible for it looks for an ul inside the li with this: `$(this).parent().addClass('open').find("ul.submenu").stop("true", "true").slideDown().addClass('active');`

Comment: yes, in that case, you should figure out styling it the same way even if the child are tabbed, or you may use ajax, without jquery ui. `$(element).click(call ajax)`.

Comment: You should edit your comments into your answer; they're easier to follow there.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Will keep that in mind. But not too much of information in these comments, just advices, so did not add to answer. Also removed useless comments.

Comment: Well after more hours of hair pulling, i discovered that `$( ".navigation ul" ).tabs();` WILL find the nested ul's, but it will treat them as new tabs, so their content will not take the place of the main ul's contents. I have also found another question on sof with the same problem, and it cant be fixed. At this point i have 2 options i think, one is to turn all the elements into li's and find a different way to hide and display them, or write my own ajax functions. Ill probably fail in both cases, but thanks for the effort Optimus.

Comment: You won't fail. SO is there to help. :) Just make efforts and you can ask questions always. You may write ajax function. They are simpler than they seem.