# Add token to every request/link after login (laravel)

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, http, middleware

This question might duplicate, but I may need some guidance.

Scenario: After user login into web, login controller in laravel will return JWT token to client and save in browser local storage. After that, every link(href) or request send to the server need the Authorisation header with token (to validate in middleware).

I have home page with:

```
<a href="{{ route('devices') }}" id="mylink">Click me</a>
<button type="submit" id="submit-button">Submit</button>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { "xCustomHeader": "xmyValue" }
});

$("#mylink").click(function(e) {

    var link = $(this).attr('href'); // get the anchor href link

    //attach the token from local storage
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { "Authorisation ": "xxxxxx" }
    });

    //get request to web php route for GET request 
    //mostly problem here??
    $.ajax({                                                           
    method: "get",                                                  
    url: link
    });


});

</script>
```

Here is web.php route:

```
Route::get('/devices', 'DevicesController@index')->name('devices');
```

Here is DevicesController class:

```
public function __construct()
{
       $this->middleware('token.verify'); //check whether the token is provided in Authorisation header
}
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $location = $this->getUnitLatLng();

        return View::make("devices")->with($location); //return view 

    }
```

Here is TokenVerify middleware class:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    try {

        $token = $request->header('Authorisation');

        if ($token) {
            return $next($request);
        } 
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $response = array('success' => false, 'data' => null, 'detail' => array('message' => 'Messages::MSG_ERROR_500', 'error' => array($ex)));
        return response()->json($response);
    }
}
```

Problem:
Seem like after login to the home page, and clicked the "Click me" anchor, the middleware is not get the authorisation header token. Href link is not able to attach header so I used ajax and get the view.

but the middleware still not get the header. any thought and amended? How can attach the header token to button/href link?

Comment: You must show us the whole process, including the login method which returns the token and the part where you store the token to the local storage

Answer (score 0):

You probably lack `preventDefault()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734749/how-make-ajax-request-with-clicking-in-the-link-not-submit-button). Also, if you're using [this](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth) library for JWT, then you could include the token in a query string like `http://api.mysite.com/me?token={yourtokenhere}`